# Release edition of DirectX 11 code can't create effect

Tags: shader, directx-11, hlsl

I used `D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory` function to create a effect from a `.fxo` file.

```
D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(&compiledShader[0], size, 
    0, md3dDevice, &mFX)
```

and I found out that the debug edition code works fine with that. But in release edition, I think something wrong with this function. The value of `mFX` variable is NULL after the function processed. But I can't tell why. I think I did exactly the demo code do, but it works fine with it.

By the way, should I use `.hlsl` files instead of `.fx` files to write shader code? Since effect framework may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Take a look at the [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) version of *Effects 11 for Direct3D 11*. It's the latest version and contains a number of fixes not present in the legacy DirectX SDK version. See [this thread](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551307) and [this thread](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) for your last questions.

Comment: You don't appear to be checking the ``HRESULT`` returned from this function for ``SUCCEEDED`` or ``FAILED``. Most likely that would give you a strong hint as to the problem.

Comment: You say you create a effect from file, so why dont you use the D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile(fileName, 0, pd3dDevice, &fx) method?